# How to encode temporal data for time series forecasting models?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, feature-extraction

I'm trying to forecast a time series using LSTMs and I have (for now) no exogenous data to aid the prediction task. As such, I was thinking of making use of the datetime attribute the time series has to generate additional features. However, I'm having trouble deciding **how to represent them**.

I have daily data, and I'm predicting the next day. I can therefore generate additional inputs such as `day_of_week`, `day_of_month`, `month`, `year`, etc. The problem is, this can be done by...

- **Label encoding** (e.g: `day_of_week` can be a single feature from 0 to 6)
- **One-hot encoding** (which I assume would be terrible, as it would create 7 features just for `day_of_week`)
- **Cossine transformations** (which I only read about in a [NVIDIA blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/three-approaches-to-encoding-time-information-as-features-for-ml-models/) with no good sources on WHY to use it) and somethings about positional encodings.

I've tried searching around google scholar but I'm struggling to find any paper that talks about the tradeoffs of each approach, so I'm kind of lost.

Are there better approaches? If so, where can I read about them, and why they're better? Thank you so much!